# Printing error in IDL: 32700+99

Tags: idl-programming-language

If I print 32700+99  in IDL it gives me -32737 but 33700.0+99 gives me 33799.0. Why is IDL print wrong for 32700+99? Of course 32700.+99 gives, 32799.0, right answer.

Answer (score 1):

The default integer in IDL is 16-bit, so the largest expressible integer is 32767.

```
IDL> print, 32767
   32767
IDL> print, 32767 + 1
  -32768
```

Floats, of course, can handle values in this range. To get a 32-bit integer, use the "L" suffix:

```
IDL> print, 32767L
       32767
IDL> print, 32767L + 1
       32768
```